# How to combine many list items into one item?

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a class named Impacts:

```
public class Impacts {
    public Impacts(string _Source, int _Number, string _Target) { 
        this.Source = _Source; 
        this.Number = _Number; 
        this.Target = _Target; 
    }
}
```

And have created a list of this class:

```
List<Impacts> ListOfImpacts = new List<Impacts>();
```

And then, I have added items to the list created:

```
ListOfImpacts.Add(new Impacts("a" , 1 , "b")); //record 1 
ListOfImpacts.Add(new Impacts("c" , 1 , "d")); //record 2 
ListOfImpacts.Add(new Impacts("d" , 1 , "a")); //record 3 
ListOfImpacts.Add(new Impacts("d" , 1 , "a")); //record 4 
ListOfImpacts.Add(new Impacts("d" , 1 , "a")); //record 5
```

I want to combine record 3 and record 4 and record 5 since they have the same "Source"="d" and same "Target"="a", so I could have:

```
new Impacts("d", 3 , "a"); // 3 is the number of iterations of this record
```

and delete the three repeated records.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you clear up one confusion - do you want the aggregated record to `Sum` or `Count`? Its hard to determine from your example because the count and sum are the same in the example you've used!

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter because every new impact has always the number variable equals 1, so the sum will be the number of iteration which means count.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var newList = ListOfImpacts.GroupBy(g => new {g.Source, g.Target})
            .Select(g => new Impacts(g.Key.Source, g.Count(), g.Key.Target))
            .ToList();
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/XOIYM52525

Answer (score 2):

```
            var newList = ListOfImpacts
            .GroupBy(i => new { i.Source, i.Target })
            .Select(i => new Impacts(i.Key.Source, i.Sum(x => x.Number), i.Key.Target))
            .ToList();
```